# State Tax Withholding for Withdrawals on IRA

Tags: taxes, ira

I am filling out paperwork to withdraw funds from my traditional IRA account. They ask, if I want state income tax withheld from my distribution, and there is a note that I may reside in a "mandatory withholding state", and if so, I should check what the "mandatory withholding minimum" is for this state.

Is New York a "mandatory withholding state"? If so what % is required for the "mandatory withholding minimum"?

Answer (score 2):

Withholding is voluntary in New York. However, except for the first $20,000 for those 59½ or older, it is taxable income.